How to go long SPX and short VIX at the same time in pine script
strategy("MovingAvg2Line Cross", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(17)
slowLength = input(2)
price = close
mafast = ta.sma(price, fastLength)
maslow = ta.sma(price, slowLength)
if (ta.crossover(mafast, maslow))
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossLE", strategy.long, comment="MA2CrossLE")
if (ta.crossunder(mafast, maslow))
    strategy.entry("MA2CrossSE", strategy.short, comment="MA2CrossSE")

if use this strategy in VIX, the long and short signals will be displayed on the chart.
such as: I sold short the VIX at the closing time on 2024-8-15 and at the same time went long SPX.Does the pine script have this function?
SPX_Data = request.security("SPX", timeframe.period, close)
I tried to use the above code in the VIX strategy script to get the daily closing price of SPX.
I checked the documentation of pine script-V5 and didn't seem to find any relevant examples. So I wanted to ask if there are any relevant examples or relevant documentation.
